# How do I insert a date in Datomic db.type/instant?

Tags: datomic

Is there a neat way to save a Date into a Datomic attribute of type db.type/instant? For instance, there is a d/tempid and d/squuid functions to produce a tempid and a squuid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Datomic doesn't provide an API endpoint for generating dates as opposed to the cases for `tempid` (something Datomic makes a specific use of) and `squuid` (the generated value is changed from a standard `uuid` and will leak time information, which precludes some secure use, but allows for better indexing performance).

In Clojure code you can use the `#inst` [reader literal](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/01_primitive-data/1-26_reader-literal.asciidoc#solution) or (java.util.Date.). You can obviously use the `java.util.Date` constructor in Java code as well (or use a library that generates the same type).